# How to list articles by year based on url?

Tags: theme-development, loop, archive-template, wp-get-archives

Hie all, I am trying to list posts by year based on the provided url (for example: wordpressite.com/2004 - this should list all articles created in 2004), unfortunately all suggested methods from previous solutions solve the problem if the year to be queried is given.

I tried creating the year.php file suggested in the wordpress hierarchy as well as date.php, but the_loop() just gives everything, not listing articles from the specific year.

```
<?php
    query_posts('posts_per_page=10');

    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'archive-content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile; endif;

    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

And this is the individual article I would like to have

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <div class="col col-sm-3 remove-left-margin">
        <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $url ?>" class="archive-card-image" />
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-9">
        <div><p class="archive-card-date"><?php the_date(); ?></p></div>
        <?php
            $categories = get_the_category();
            if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
                echo '<div class="card-article-tag"><a class="archive-card-topic" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a></div>';
            }
        ?>
        <div><h4 class="archive-card-title"><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></h4></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I am still very new to wordpress, would appreciate any help.

```
wp_get_archives('type=yearly')
```

The documentation does not state how I can use my article structure mentioned above.

Comment: WordPress supports date archives (like the yearly archive) out of the box, so you shouldn't need a secondary query to generate this. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the OP? Note that using `query_posts` is no longer considered good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, what should I use in place of `query_posts` and you mentioned it supports yearly archive out of the box, it doesn't seem to work in both my date.php and year.php both files use the code in the question.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to have something like `wordpressite.com/2019` to list articles from the year 2019? We can check the year archive on WordPress installs like https://blog.wordpress.tv/2019/ and https://wptavern.com/2019. WordPress uses the main query to generate this and if we need to modify the main query we can use e.g. `pre_get_posts` action, but I don't see a need for it here. If we need to change the corresponding theme template we can look at the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#date), like you've done here.

Comment: Thanks, so how exactly do I list articles by year, as I mentioned I tried date.php (as shown above) and year.php (same as above) this is what the template hierarchy states but its not working `wordpressite.com/2019` shows results from 2018 and 17 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Avoid using `query_posts()`

Please don't use

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=10');
```

in your `date.php` template file as it will **override the main query instance** and thus affect the main loop. This can truly ruin the day!

If you need to modify e.g. the `posts_per_page` for the main date query, use the `pre_get_posts` action to modify the query variables, before the database request is made.

There's a harsh warning on `query_posts()` usage in the [manual](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/).

So **remove** that part toghether with `wp_reset_query()` and it should work again!

### Yearly Date Archive: Modifying the number of posts

Here's an example how to change the posts per page for the yearly date archive:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() || ! $query->is_year() ) {
        return;
    }
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 ); // Adjust the number to your needs!
} );
```

Here we use the [`is_year()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_year/) to target the yearly archive queries and the [`is_main_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_main_query) to target only main queries.

### Yearly Date Archive: Supporting the `date-year.php` template file.

We can also add a support for the `date-year.php` template file, by modifying the template filter [example](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#example) from the manual:

```
/**
 * Add a support for date-year.php template files.
 */
add_filter( 'date_template', function( $templates ) {
    if ( ! is_year() ) {
        return $templates;
    }
    if ( ! is_array( $templates ) && ! empty( $templates ) ) { 
        $templates = locate_template( [ "date-year.php", $templates ], false ); 
    } elseif ( empty( $templates ) ) { 
        $templates = locate_template( "date-year.php", false ); 
    } else {
        $new_template = locate_template( [ "date-year.php" ] ); 
        if ( ! empty( $new_template ) ) { 
            array_unshift( $templates, $new_template ); 
        } 
    } 
    return $templates; 
} );
```

That way we are only working with the yearly date archive and not the others, like month and day if using the `date.php` template file.

### Note

Add the code snippets into your `functions.php` file in the current theme directory or create a plugin. Never copy/paste some code snippets from the internet directly to a live site. Always test first on dev/local installs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that indeed was the problem. Is there an alternative for listing posts per page?

Comment: Glad to hear it helped solving your problem. You can change the number of posts within the `/wp-admin` backend settings, but it will change other archives as well. Note that if you use the `pre_get_posts` hook, you need to add conditionals to target the main (frontend) query for only the date (year) archives - otherwise you will modify all requests generated from `WP_Query`.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example how to change the number of posts on the yearly date archives.

Comment: I also updated it with a support for the `date-year.php` template file.